# I found out that a CECM for a double decker bus was faulty.The new unit I tried to fit ended up giving same fault.Does the new unit need programming

Tags: electronics

The good second hand CECM I later fitted was able to down load and the fault fixed.Do I need to program the new unit.The Chassis Electronic Control Unit(CECM) is for a volvo double decker bus

Comment: If it does, then perhaps the old one only needed re-programming... if not then there is another fault to find which may mean the other CECM is not faulty. I would go through the test procedure as I am guessing you just tried changing the unit...

Comment: The fault came about after loose engine ecu got disturbed whilst engine was running.Engine just cut off.